# Safe Record field query

Tags: haskell

Is there a clean way to avoid the following boilerplate:

Given a Record data type definition....

```
data Value = A{ name::String } | B{ name::String } | C{}
```

write a function that safely returns `name`

```
getName :: Value -> Maybe String
getName A{ name=x } = Just x
getName B{ name=x } = Just x
getName C{} = Nothing
```

I know you can do this with Template Haskell, I am looking for a cleaner soln than that, perhaps a GHC extension or something else I've overlooked.

Comment: Won't this fail to compile in vanilla GHC anyways since you can't have overloaded record fields?

Comment: @jkeuhlen No. It creates a partial function `name :: Value -> String` which fails with `*** Exception: No match in record selector name` on `name C`. You are thinking of records with shared fields in _different_ datatypes.

Comment: You introduce the need for such boilerplate in your datatype definition. Instead you could write `data Value = AorB Bool String | C; getName (AorB _ x) = x; getName _ = Nothing`

Comment: @Alec thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @user2407038 It is easy to do that refactor in a small toy example, but it won't always work so easily....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens)'s [Template Haskell helpers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html) do the right thing when they encounter partial record fields.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}


import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens


data T = A { _name :: String }
       | B { _name :: String }
       | C

makeLenses ''T
```

This'll generate a [`Traversal'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t:Traversal-39-) called `name` that selects the `String` inside the `A` and `B` constructors and does nothing in the `C` case.

```
ghci> :i name
name :: Traversal' T String  -- Defined at test.hs:11:1
```

So we can use [the `^?` operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:-94--63-) (which is a flipped synonym for [`preview`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:preview)) from [`Control.Lens.Fold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html) to pull out `Maybe` the name.

```
getName :: T -> Maybe String
getName = (^? name)
```

You can also make [`Prism'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#t:Prism-39-)s for the constructors of your datatype, and choose the first one of those which matches using [`<|>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-). This version is useful when the fields of your constructors have different names, but you do have to remember to update your extractor function when you add constructors.

```
makePrisms ''T

getName' :: T -> Maybe String
getName' t = t^?_A <|> t^?_B
```

`lens` is pretty useful!

Comment: Benjamin, to use Lens, do we have to always start the field name with '_'? Why? Thanks!

Comment: You don’t have to! It’s just the default naming convention that `makeLenses` recognises. You can configure it to match whatever naming convention you want, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a GADT? I do not know if you are interested in using only records. But, I fell that GADTs provide a clean solution to your problem, since you can restrict what constructors are valid by refining types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Teste where

 data Value a where
    A :: String -> Value String
    B :: String -> Value String
    C :: Value ()

 name :: Value String -> String
 name (A s) = s
 name (B s) = s
```

Notice that both `A` and `B` produce `Value String` values while `C` produces `Value ()`. When you define function

```
name :: Value String -> String
```

it specifically says that you can only pass a value that has a string in it. So, you can only pattern match on `A` or `B` values. This is useful to avoid the need of `Maybe` in code.

Comment: Maybe you meant `A :: { name :: String } -> Value String` and `B :: { name :: String } -> Value String`? That way, `name :: Value String -> String` is automatically generated for you.

Comment: @Alec: I've tried such syntax on my GHC version 8.0.1 and it doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Do you have `-XGADTs` enabled? If so, it should work (and has for already many GHC versions). See [this](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-algebraic-data-types-gadts).

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, rather it moves it to a different place. `Value String` is not isomorphic to the original type. You will still need a function of type `(exists x . Value x) -> Maybe (Value String)`. If the OP could rely on always having a value of type `Value String` as opposed to `exists x . Value x` then they would not have written the `C` constructor in the first place.